# C++ - Cannot compare const and non-const template types using operator overload

Tags: c++, templates, comparison, constants, operator-keyword

I'm new to Stack Overflow and C++! So here is the problem:

The goal is to create container class using next interface:

IContainer.h:

```
class ElemNotFound {};

template < class ElemType, class IndexType > class IContainer
{
public:
    virtual const ElemType& GetElem(const IndexType& index) const throw (ElemNotFound) = 0;
    virtual void PutElem(const IndexType& index, const ElemType& elem) throw () = 0;
};
```

The current code that uses that interface is:

```
    #include "IContainer.h"
    #include <vector>

    class Container : public IContainer < class ElemType, class IndexType >
    {

    private:

        struct ContainerElement
        {
            IndexType& Index;
            ElemType& Data;
        };

        std::vector < ContainerElement > MyVector;
        std::vector < ContainerElement > ::iterator MyIterator;

    public:

        // EDIT: that operator== part is incorrect as
        // failed attempt to circumvent inability to compare custom types
        friend bool operator== (IndexType& x, const IndexType& y)
        {
            if (x == y) return 1;
            else return 0;
        }

        const ElemType& GetElem(const IndexType& index)
        {
            try
            {

                MyIterator = MyVector.begin();
                while (MyIterator != MyVector.end())            

                {
                    if (MyIterator->Index == index)
                    // PROBLEM: missing operator "==" for IndexType == const IndexType
                    {
                        // do useful things
                    }
                    MyIterator++;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e) // everything down below is a placeholder
            {
                throw (ElemNotFound) = 0;
            }
        }

        void PutElem(const IndexType& index, const ElemType& elem)
        {

        }
    };
```

Direct comparison of IndexType and const IndexType (using "==") is not working for the reason I am not aware of. I want to compare custom index in my vector and index I use in the function to get element out of container. Using operator overload "==" for custom types didn't work either. Should it be incorrect inheritance or incorrect use of operator overload - I do not know!

So the question is: how to compare const and non-const custom type variables in the class that uses templates?

Comment: Is there a reason your `operator==` function don't take *both* arguments by constant reference? And won't that comparison in the operator function call itself recursively anyway?

Comment: Joachim, that portion of code was just an attempt to circumvent inability to write `(MyIterator->Index == index)` directly. I know that it is incorrect - the error is still present. Why I can't compare custom type and const custom type - I do not know. Couldn't find the answer in C++ standart description and C++ literature either.

Comment: Where are `ElemType` and `IndexType` defined?

Comment: @SergeiBorodin Non-const types implicitely convert to const types. Just compare two const types

Comment: And shouldn't operator== compare two `const Container&` instead of IndexTypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fundamental problem with your code; all other errors you see only hide the real one. It's this line:

```
class Container : public IContainer < class ElemType, class IndexType >
```

The `class ElemType` and `class IndexType` arguments are misleading. These are really **forward declarations of classes which are never defined**. The fact that their names are identical to the *template parameter names* of `IContainer` is only a coincidence.

In other words: You are instantiating your template with incomplete classes.

This means that the compiler knows almost nothing about them. Do they have public constructors? Do they even support `operator==`?

Consider this extremely simplified version of your program:

```
template < class ElemType, class IndexType > class IContainer
{
public:
    virtual void PutElem(const IndexType& index, const ElemType& elem);
};

class Container : public IContainer < class ElemType, class IndexType >
{
public:
    void PutElem(const IndexType& index, const ElemType& elem)
    {
        bool b1 = index == index;
        bool b2 = elem == elem;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Container c;
}
```

Compilation errors (depending on your compiler):

```
stackoverflow.cpp(12) : error C2676: binary '==' : 'const IndexType' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
stackoverflow.cpp(13) : error C2676: binary '==' : 'const ElemType' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

There you have it: the classes are undefined and the compiler doesn't even know if they support `==`.

---

Further problems:

- `Container`'s `GetElem` is apparently supposed to override the `GetElem` in the base class, but it is `const` there. Overrides distinguish between `const` and non-`const`.
- The `MyIterator = MyVector.begin();` line will not work in a `const` function because `MyIterator` is modified (and is not `mutable`).
- Your template will not work with primitive types like `int` because you cannot overload `operator==` if both operands are of primitive type.

---

I'm not completely sure what your code's intention really is, but perhaps you want `Container` to be a template as well, used to generate `Container` classes?

You can do so like this:

```
template < class ElemType, class IndexType >
class Container : public IContainer < ElemType, IndexType >
```

That's the starting point; you can then fix all other errors individually. Feel free to ask individual questions for them.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your vast answer! Indeed, I was catching the wind and had a fundumental problem with defining template classes. I got rid of `operator==` as long as I don't need it and everything works fine. And other minor advices were very helpful too. Serves me a lesson.

Comment: @SergeiBorodin: You're welcome :) While we're at it, you should get rid of exception specifications (such as the `throw (ElemNotFound)` part of the function declaration). They were never fully supported by all major compilers and have generally been quite useless for technical and semantical reasons which a single comment cannot explain in detail. In fact, exception specifications are **deprecated** in modern versions of C++, and the only useful variant, `throw()` to indicate that *no* exception is thrown, has been superseded by `noexcept`.

Comment: @SergeiBorodin: And it's good practice to derive custom exceptions directly or indirectly from `std::exception`.

Comment: Thank you one more time :) I already was into this question because header is some part of old code (as you mentioned `noexcept` from C++11) which is not mine and `throw (ElemNotFound) = 0` and `throw () = 0;` is quite unusual for my opinion. I'm new to C++ (though I know C99) but using assignment in method declaration is odd to me. And thank you for `std::exception` note - point taken.

Comment: @SergeiBorodin: These are not assignments but the C++ way of marking a function as pure virtual (like an abstract method in Java). AFAIK the funny syntax was once chosen to avoid adding a new keyword to the language.